# Substring until space

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have string like this:

```
Some data of the string Job ID_Of_the_job some other data of the string
```

I need to get this **ID_Of_the_job**

I here this stored in notes string variable

```
intIndex = notes.IndexOf("Job ")
strJob = notes.Substring(intIndex+4, ???)
```

I dont know how to get the lenght of this job.

Thanks for help,
Marc

Comment: `IndexOf` has an overload which takes the index to start searching at. You can use this to look for the next space which appears after "Job "

Comment: Why is this tagged with VB.NET?

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, somethimes it is with "_", somethimes with "\" or "'-"

Comment: @canton7 yes, I could do that but how I get then the lenght of the string till the end? notes.lenght - intIndex is too much

Comment: What's wrong with `notes.Substring(intIndex+4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using `string.IndexOf`, here's a solution which builds on that.

Note that there's an [overload of `String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_) which takes a parameter saying where to start searching.

We've managed to find the beginning of the Job ID, by doing:

```
int startIndex = notes.IndexOf("Job ") + "Job ".Length;
```

`startIndex` is the index of the "I" in "ID_Of_the_job".

We can then use `IndexOf` again to find the next space -- which will be the space following "ID_Of_the_job":

```
int endIndex = notes.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);
```

We can then use `Substring`:

```
string jobId = notes.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Note that there's no error-handling here: if either of the `IndexOf` fails to find the thing you're looking for, it will return -1, and your code will do strange things. It would be a good idea to handle these cases!

---

Another, terser solution is to use Regex.

```
string jobId = Regex.Match(notes, @"Job (\S+)").Groups[1].Value
```

The regular expression `Job (\S+)` looks for the text "Job ", followed by 1 or more non-whitespace characters. It puts those non-whitespace characters into a capture group (which becomes `Groups[1]`), which we can read out.

In this case, `jobId` will be an empty string if the regex doesn't match.

See these working on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IT0Iq8).

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd make life easy, split the string on spaces and take the string after the array slot that had Job in it:

```
var notes = "Some data of the string Job ID_Of_the_job some other data of the string";
var bits = notes.Split();
var job = bits[bits.IndexOf("Job") + 1]; //or Array.IndexOf..
```

If you're on a recent .net and know the job number will occur within the first 10 (say) words, then you can stop splitting after a certain number of words, with e.g. `Split(new[]{' '}, 10)` - this gives the first 9 words then the rest of the string in the 10th slot which could be a useful performance boost

You could also pull this fairly easily with regex:

```
var r = new Regex("Job (?<j>[^ ]+?)");
var m = r.Match(notes);
var job = m.Groups["j"].Value;
```

If you can more accurately define the format of a job number e.g. "it's between 2-3 digits, then a underscore, slash or hyphen, followed by 4 digits", then you don't even have to use `Job` to locate it, you can put the pattern into the regex:

```
var r = new Regex(@"(?<j>\d{2,3}[-_\\]\d{4})");
```

That will pick out a string of the given pattern (\digits {2 to 3 of}, then [hyphen or underscore or slash], then \digits {4 of}).. For example

Comment: Easier and if the string is not large also good, but you should handle the cases that there is no `Job` and that there is no space after the Job.

Comment: Those conditions were not part of the spec?

Comment: thanks! I cannot mark 4 answers as solution sadly :(

Comment: @logancapp indeed, you should mark the answer that contains the code you end up using, but there is no limit on the number of other answers (including the one you mark as accepted) that you can upvote as "useful" - things you find on SO are useful if they teach you something/help towards understanding and solving the problem or contain pointers you end up using

Answer (score 0):

First step you already did: find the string `"Job id "`. Second step is to split result by `' '` to extract id.

```
var input = "Some data of the string Job ID_Of_the_job some other data of the string";
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(input.IndexOf("Job") + 4).Split(' ')[0]);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DxnU2y).

Comment: thanks! I cannot mark 4 answers as solution sadly :(

Comment: No need for [thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269681/1997232) ;).